# Log-likelihood calculation given estimated parameters

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, model-fitting, log-likelihood

In general: I want to calculate the (log) likelihood of data *N* given the estimated model parameters from data *O*.

More specifically, I want to know if my `ll_given_modPars` function below exists in one of the may R packages dealing with data modeling (`lme4`, `glmm`, etc.) as shown in this abstract example (not run):

```
library(lme4)
o_model <- lmer(observed ~ fixed.id + (1|random.id), data = O, REML = F)
n_logLik <- ll_given_modPars(model.estimates = o_model, data = N)
```

The fictional example above is on a linear mixed model for simplicity but I would like to eventually do this in a generalized linear mixed model which deals with the Poisson family or directly the negative binomial (for `lme4`: `glmer(..., family="poisson")` or `glmer.nb` ).

From what I could see most packages deal with parameter estimation (great, I need that) but then compare models on the same data with different combinations of fixed and random effects using `anova` or something to that extent which is not what I want to do.

I want the log likelihood for the same parameters on different data.

The main attempts made:

1. After not finding a function which seems to be doing that I thought of 'simply' tweaking the `lme4` code to my purposes: it calculates the log likelihood for parameters given the data so I thought I could use the same framework but not have it optimize over different parameters but isolate the likelihood calculation function and just give it the parameters and the data. Unfortunately the code is a bit above my current skills https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/R/nbinom.R (I get a bit lost in how they use the objects over which they optimize).
2. I thought of doing the likelihood calculation myself, starting with a linear mixed model and then working my way up to more involved ones. But already with this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20980116/how-does-lmer-from-the-r-package-lme4-compute-log-likelihood) I'm having a hard time following the math and even when using the formula as specified the obtained log-likelihood is still different (I don't know why, see code in appendix) and I fear it will take me too long before I'll be able to do it for the more involved models (such as Poisson or negative binomial)

At this point I'm not sure what avenue is best to pursue and would appreciate any input you might have.

Appendix: Trying to calculate the log-likelihood (or finding a closed form approximation) based on [How does lmer (from the R package lme4) compute log likelihood?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20980116/how-does-lmer-from-the-r-package-lme4-compute-log-likelihood). `lmer` (from `lme4`) gives a log-likelihood of -17.8 and I get -45.56

```
library(lme4)
set.seed(7)
n <- 2  # number of groups
m <- 4  # number of instances per group
fixed.effect <- c(0, -2, -1, 1) 
tau <- 5 # standard deviation of random effects
sigma <- 2 # standard deviation of error
random.effect <- rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=tau)
sim.data <- data.frame(GROUP.ID=as.factor(rep(1:n, each=m)),
                     GROUP.EFFECT=rep(random.effect, each=m),
                     INSTANCE.ID=as.factor(rep(1:m, times=n)),
                     INSTANCE.EFFECT=rep(fixed.effect, times=n))
# calculate expected Y value
sim.data$EXPECT.Y <- sim.data$GROUP.EFFECT + sim.data$INSTANCE.EFFECT
# now observe Y value, assuming normally distributed with fixed std. deviation
sim.data$OBS.Y <- rnorm(nrow(sim.data), mean=sim.data$EXPECT.Y, sigma)


model <- lmer(OBS.Y ~ INSTANCE.ID + (1|GROUP.ID), data = sim.data, REML=F)
summary(model)

toy.model.var <- VarCorr(model)
toy.model.sigma <- attr(toy.model.var, 'sc') # corresponds to the epsilon, residual standard deviation
toy.model.tau.squared <- toy.model.var[[1]][1] # corresponds to variance of random effects
toy.model.betas <- model@beta

# left product, spread within gropus
toy.data <- rbind(sim.data$OBS.Y[1:4], sim.data$OBS.Y[5:8])
toy.mean.adj <- rbind(toy.data[1,] - mean(unlist(toy.data[1,])), toy.data[2,] - mean(unlist(toy.data[2,])))
toy.mean.adj.prod1 <- prod(dnorm(unlist(toy.mean.adj[1,]), mean = 0, sd = toy.model.sigma))
toy.mean.adj.prod2 <- prod(dnorm(unlist(toy.mean.adj[2,]), mean = 0, sd = toy.model.sigma))
toy.mean.adj.final.prod <- toy.mean.adj.prod1 * toy.mean.adj.prod2

# right product, spread between gropus
toy.mean.beta.adj <- rbind(mean(unlist(toy.data[1,])) - toy.model.betas, mean(unlist(toy.data[2,])) - toy.model.betas)
toy.mean.beta.adj[1,] <- toy.mean.beta.adj[1,] - c(0, toy.model.betas[1], toy.model.betas[1], toy.model.betas[1])
toy.mean.beta.adj[2,] <- toy.mean.beta.adj[2,] - c(0, toy.model.betas[1], toy.model.betas[1], toy.model.betas[1])
toy.mean.beta.adj.prod1 <- prod(dnorm(unlist(toy.mean.beta.adj[1,]), mean = 0, sd = sqrt(toy.model.sigma^2/4 + toy.model.tau.squared)) * sqrt(2/4*pi*toy.model.sigma^2))
toy.mean.beta.adj.prod2 <- prod(dnorm(unlist(toy.mean.beta.adj[2,]), mean = 0, sd = sqrt(toy.model.sigma^2/4 + toy.model.tau.squared)) * sqrt(2/4*pi*toy.model.sigma^2))

toy.mean.beta.adj.final.prod <- toy.mean.beta.adj.prod1 * toy.mean.beta.adj.prod2

toy.total.prod <- toy.mean.adj.final.prod * toy.mean.beta.adj.final.prod
log(toy.total.prod)
```

EDIT: A helpful link was provided in the comments (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/271903/understand-marginal-likelihood-of-mixed-effects-models). Converting my example from above I can replicate the log-likelihood

```
library(mvtnorm)

z = getME(model, "Z")
zt =  getME(model, "Zt")
psi = bdiag(replicate(2, toy.model.tau.squared, simplify=FALSE))

betw = z%*%psi%*%zt
err = Diagonal(8, sigma(model)^2)
v = betw + err

dmvnorm(sim.data$OBS.Y, predict(model, re.form=NA), as.matrix(v), log=TRUE)
```

Comment: for ols and some other model objects, `stats::logLik()` is defined, e.g. `logLik(lm(Sepal.Length ~ ., iris))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I did not manage to come up with a closed form solution for all of them, I did manage to reproduce the log-likelihoods using numerical integration. I have posted below small examples for how it works in the LMM setting (assuming normal residuals random effects) as well as the GLMM with Poisson and Negative-Binomial. Note that especially the latter one tends so differ ever so slightly when you increase the sample size. My guess is that there is some rounding happening somewhere but for my purposes the precision achieved here is good enough. I will for now accept my own answer but if someone posts a closed form for the Poisson or the Negative-Binomial I will happily accept your answer :)

```
library(lme4)
library(mvtnorm)

################################################################################
# LMM numerical integration

set.seed(7)

n <- 2  # number of groups
m <- 4  # number of instances per group
fixed.effect <- c(0, -2, -1, 1)
tau <- 5 # standard deviation of random effects
sigma <- 2 # standard deviation of error
random.effect <- rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=tau)
normal.data <- data.frame(GROUP.ID=as.factor(rep(1:n, each=m)),
                       GROUP.EFFECT=rep(random.effect, each=m),
                       INSTANCE.ID=as.factor(rep(1:m, times=n)),
                       INSTANCE.EFFECT=rep(fixed.effect, times=n))
# calculate expected Y value
normal.data$EXPECT.Y <- normal.data$GROUP.EFFECT + normal.data$INSTANCE.EFFECT
# now observe Y value, assuming normally distributed with fixed std. deviation
normal.data$OBS.Y <- rnorm(nrow(normal.data), mean=normal.data$EXPECT.Y, sigma)


normal.model <- lmer(OBS.Y ~ INSTANCE.ID + (1|GROUP.ID), data = normal.data, REML=F)
summary(normal.model)

normal.model.var <- VarCorr(normal.model)
normal.model.sigma <- attr(normal.model.var, 'sc') # corresponds to the epsilon, residual standard deviation
normal.model.tau.squared <- normal.model.var[[1]][1] # corresponds to variance of random effects
normal.model.betas <- normal.model@beta

normal.group.tau <- sqrt(normal.model.tau.squared)
normal.group.sigma <- sigma(normal.model)
normal.group.beta <- predict(normal.model, re.form=NA)[1:4]

integrate_group1 <- function(x){
  p1 <- dnorm(normal.data$OBS.Y[1] - normal.group.beta[1] - x, mean = 0, sd = normal.group.sigma) * dnorm(x, mean = 0, sd = normal.group.tau)
  p2 <- dnorm(normal.data$OBS.Y[2] - normal.group.beta[2] - x, mean = 0, sd = normal.group.sigma)
  p3 <- dnorm(normal.data$OBS.Y[3] - normal.group.beta[3] - x, mean = 0, sd = normal.group.sigma)
  p4 <- dnorm(normal.data$OBS.Y[4] - normal.group.beta[4] - x, mean = 0, sd = normal.group.sigma)

  p_out <- p1 * p2 * p3 * p4
  p_out
}

normal.group1.integration <- integrate(integrate_group1, lower = -10*normal.group.tau, upper = 10*normal.group.tau, subdivisions = 10000L, rel.tol = 1e-10, abs.tol = 1e-50)$value[1]

integrate_group2 <- function(x){
  p1 <- dnorm(normal.data$OBS.Y[5] - normal.group.beta[1] - x, mean = 0, sd = normal.group.sigma) * dnorm(x, mean = 0, sd = normal.group.tau)
  p2 <- dnorm(normal.data$OBS.Y[6] - normal.group.beta[2] - x, mean = 0, sd = normal.group.sigma)
  p3 <- dnorm(normal.data$OBS.Y[7] - normal.group.beta[3] - x, mean = 0, sd = normal.group.sigma)
  p4 <- dnorm(normal.data$OBS.Y[8] - normal.group.beta[4] - x, mean = 0, sd = normal.group.sigma)

  p_out <- p1 * p2 * p3 * p4
  p_out
}

normal.group2.integration <- integrate(integrate_group2, lower = -10*normal.group.tau, upper = 10*normal.group.tau, subdivisions = 10000L, rel.tol = 1e-10, abs.tol = 1e-50)$value[1]

log(normal.group1.integration) + log(normal.group2.integration)


#################################
# Poisson numerical integration
set.seed(13) #13
n <- 2  # number of groups
m <- 4  # number of instances per group
# effect sizes are much smaller since they are exponentiated
fixed.effect <- c(0, -0.2, -0.1, 0.2)
tau <- 1.5 # standard deviation of random effects
# sigma <- 1.5 # standard deviation of error
random.effect <- rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=tau)  # guide effect
poisson.data <- data.frame(GROUP.ID=as.factor(rep(1:n, each=m)),
                       GROUP.EFFECT=rep(random.effect, each=m),
                       INSTANCE.ID=as.factor(rep(1:m, times=n)),
                       INSTANCE.EFFECT=rep(fixed.effect, times=n))
# calculate expected Y value
poisson.data$EXPECT.Y <- exp(poisson.data$GROUP.EFFECT + poisson.data$INSTANCE.EFFECT)
# now observe Y value, assuming normally distributed with fixed std. deviation
poisson.data$OBS.Y <- rpois(nrow(poisson.data), poisson.data$EXPECT.Y)

poisson.model <- glmer(OBS.Y ~ INSTANCE.ID + (1|GROUP.ID), data = poisson.data, family="poisson")
summary(poisson.model)

poisson.model.var <- VarCorr(poisson.model)
poisson.model.sigma <- attr(poisson.model.var, 'sc') # corresponds to the epsilon, residual standard deviation
poisson.model.tau.squared <- poisson.model.var[[1]][1] # corresponds to variance of random effects
poisson.model.betas <- poisson.model@beta

poisson.group.tau <- sqrt(poisson.model.tau.squared)
poisson.group.sigma <- sigma(poisson.model)
poisson.group.beta <- predict(poisson.model, re.form=NA)[1:4]

integrate_group1 <- function(x){
  p1 <- dpois(poisson.data$OBS.Y[1], lambda = exp(poisson.group.beta[1] + x)) * dnorm(x, mean = 0, sd = poisson.group.tau)
  p2 <- dpois(poisson.data$OBS.Y[2], lambda = exp(poisson.group.beta[2] + x))
  p3 <- dpois(poisson.data$OBS.Y[3], lambda = exp(poisson.group.beta[3] + x))
  p4 <- dpois(poisson.data$OBS.Y[4], lambda = exp(poisson.group.beta[4] + x))

  p_out <- p1 * p2 * p3 * p4
  p_out
}

poisson.group1.integration <- integrate(integrate_group1, lower = -10*poisson.group.tau, upper = 10*poisson.group.tau, subdivisions = 10000L, rel.tol = 1e-10, abs.tol = 1e-50)$value[1]

integrate_group2 <- function(x){
  p1 <- dpois(poisson.data$OBS.Y[5], lambda = exp(poisson.group.beta[1] + x)) * dnorm(x, mean = 0, sd = poisson.group.tau)
  p2 <- dpois(poisson.data$OBS.Y[6], lambda = exp(poisson.group.beta[2] + x))
  p3 <- dpois(poisson.data$OBS.Y[7], lambda = exp(poisson.group.beta[3] + x))
  p4 <- dpois(poisson.data$OBS.Y[8], lambda = exp(poisson.group.beta[4] + x))

  p_out <- p1 * p2 * p3 * p4
  p_out
}

poisson.group2.integration <- integrate(integrate_group2, lower = -10*poisson.group.tau, upper = 10*poisson.group.tau, subdivisions = 10000L, rel.tol = 1e-10, abs.tol = 1e-50)$value[1]

log(poisson.group1.integration) + log(poisson.group2.integration)



#############
# Negative-Binomial numerical integration

set.seed(13) #13
n <- 100  # number of groups
m <- 4  # number of instances per group
# effect sizes are much smaller since they are exponentiated
fixed.effect <- c(0, -0.2, -0.1, 0.2)
tau <- 1.5 # standard deviation of random effects
theta <- 0.5
# sigma <- 1.5 # standard deviation of error
random.effect <- rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=tau)  # guide effect
nb.data <- data.frame(GROUP.ID=as.factor(rep(1:n, each=m)),
                       GROUP.EFFECT=rep(random.effect, each=m),
                       INSTANCE.ID=as.factor(rep(1:m, times=n)),
                       INSTANCE.EFFECT=rep(fixed.effect, times=n))
# calculate expected Y value
nb.data$EXPECT.Y <- exp(nb.data$GROUP.EFFECT + nb.data$INSTANCE.EFFECT)
# now observe Y value, assuming normally distributed with fixed std. deviation
nb.data$OBS.Y <- rnbinom(nrow(nb.data), mu = nb.data$EXPECT.Y, size = theta)

nb.model <- glmer.nb(OBS.Y ~ INSTANCE.ID + (1|GROUP.ID), data = nb.data)
summary(nb.model)

nb.model.var <- VarCorr(nb.model)
nb.model.sigma <- attr(nb.model.var, 'sc') # corresponds to the epsilon, residual standard deviation
nb.model.tau.squared <- nb.model.var[[1]][1] # corresponds to variance of random effects
nb.model.betas <- nb.model@beta

nb.group.tau <- sqrt(nb.model.tau.squared)
nb.group.beta <- predict(nb.model, re.form=NA)[1:4]
nb.group.dispersion <- getME(nb.model, "glmer.nb.theta")

integration_function_generator <- function(input.obs, input.beta, input.dispersion, input.tau){
  function(x){
    p1 <- dnbinom(input.obs[1], mu = exp(input.beta[1] + x), size = input.dispersion) * dnorm(x, mean = 0, sd = input.tau)
    p2 <- dnbinom(input.obs[2], mu = exp(input.beta[2] + x), size = input.dispersion)
    p3 <- dnbinom(input.obs[3], mu = exp(input.beta[3] + x), size = input.dispersion)
    p4 <- dnbinom(input.obs[4], mu = exp(input.beta[4] + x), size = input.dispersion)

    p_out <- p1 * p2 * p3 * p4
    p_out
  }
}

nb.all.group.integrations <- c()
for(i in 1:n){
  temp.obs <- nb.data$OBS.Y[(1:4)+(i-1)*4]
  temp_integrate_function <- integration_function_generator(temp.obs, nb.group.beta, nb.group.dispersion, nb.group.tau)
  temp.integration <- integrate(temp_integrate_function, lower = -10*nb.group.tau, upper = 10*nb.group.tau, subdivisions = 10000L, rel.tol = 1e-10, abs.tol = 1e-50)$value[1]
  nb.all.group.integrations <- c(nb.all.group.integrations, temp.integration)
}
sum(log(nb.all.group.integrations))
```